# How to find data in database in Spring Boot by my variable?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

I have this code:

```
@GetMapping("/notes/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Note> getNoteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
    Note note = noteRepository.findOne(id);
    if(note == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(note);
}
```

So this method just finds information by the sent id.
The method `noteRepository.findOne()` accepts only `Long` or `class extends org.springframework.data.domain.Example`

I want to retrive data by my own variable `"secretkey"` (String). How can I do this?

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

Use this method :

```
@GetMapping("/notes/byKey/{secretKey}")
 public ResponseEntity<Note> getNoteById(@PathVariable(value = "secretKey") String secretKey) {
 Note note = noteRepository.findBySecretKey(secretKey);
 if(note == null) {
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
 }
 return ResponseEntity.ok().body(note);
```

}

in your `NoteRepository`class add this method:

```
Note findBySecretKey(String secretKey);
```

note that I also changed the request path.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are using Spring Data:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="note")
public class Note {

 @Id 
 @GeneratedAuto
 private Long id;

 @Column(name="secretKey")
 private String secretKey;

 // getters, setters
}


//Repository
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, Long> {

 List<Note> findBySecretKey(String secretKey);
}


// Controller
@GetMapping(path = "/notes/secretKey/{secretKey}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Note> getNoteBySecretKey(
 @PathVariable(value = "secretKey") String secretKey) {

 Note note = noteRepository.findBySecretKey(secretKey);
 if(note == null) {
  return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
 }
 return ResponseEntity.ok().body(note);
}
```